# Windows Server:: Replicate Built-In Administrator Account

Tags: windows, file, server, account, administrator

I created a secondary account on my Windows Server 2008 R2 installation. So now I have the build-in Administrator account and my custom one. I included my custom account in all user groups, including Administrators, but I can't seem to replicate the build-in Administrator completely. There are many folders that I do not have permission to create files in through the File Explorer, and of what I can recall, opening it as administrator won't help. I want to be able to do just about anything, just like the built-in Administrator account, on my custom one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch that, I've managed to answer my own question. Apparently the last step missing to fully replicate the built-in Administrator account was to disable UAC. Just posting this in here for anyone curious.